# TI Nspire BASIC - Extract coefficients from Equation

Tags: calculator, basic, ti-basic

I intend to write a function in TI-BASIC on my CAS calculator that takes a mathematical expression (a quadratic specifically) as a parameter and 'completes the square'.

To do this, I need to compute with the coefficients of the variable 'x' in the argument.

Is there a way to 'extract' the coefficients of x from the argument?

(A friend sensibly suggested to pass each coefficient as different arguments,
which would work, but seems messy and unnecessary).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beg your pardon,
There's a lovely polyCoeffs() function

```
ListOfCoef = polyCoeffs(quadratic)
```